# Not getting data and Extra in OnNewIntent() with launch mode New Task and SingleTop

Tags: android, android-intent

I am Launching activity with below Intent :

**intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);**
intent.putExtra("uri",data);

And i got call at onNewIntent() but when getting "uri" from intent, it gives me null.

Even intent.hasExtra("uri") also false.Altgough i have put it in intent.